# Can't connect jdbc with mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, jdbc, upgrade

When trying to connect from MyBatis and jdbc to mysql 5.6 I get an exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: communications link failure
```

This only happened after upgrading from 5.1 to 5.6.

I looked at the driver [official page.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) the latest available driver is for 5.1.

Comment: Make sure that the server has not been configured to ignore network connections or (if you are attempting to connect remotely) that it has not been configured to listen only locally on its network interfaces. If the server was started with --skip-networking, it will not accept TCP/IP connections at all. If the server was started with --bind-address=127.0.0.1, it will listen for TCP/IP connections only locally on the loopback interface and will not accept remote connections.

Comment: also Check to make sure that there is no firewall blocking access to MySQL. Your firewall may be configured on the basis of the application being executed, or the port number used by MySQL for communication (3306 by default). Under Linux or Unix, check your IP tables (or similar) configuration to ensure that the port has not been blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the configuration in

/etc/my.cnf

it looks like 5.6 doesn't accept all configuration items as 5.1. 
I had to remove

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

to start the mysql-server

and had to remove

```
bind-address    =   ?
```

for to resolve the exception I was getting in my question above. and start tomcat applications.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too, then I realized I didn't have the WAMP server open. Check if you have opened WampServer (or LampServer if you are using Linux).

Comment: I am on centos server, and mysqld is up

Comment: Now that I don't have enough reputation to comment on any post, shouldn't I try to help?